# Excel VBA Coding: need to create a loop that identifies data fill in one column and returns specified value in another column

Tags: excel

'Create a value of "1" in cells A2:A101 for cells that contain data in B2:B101 then  create value of 2 in cells A102:A201 for cells B102:B201 that contain data and so on to infinity

Comment: Please include your efforts. Also, infinity isn't an option with Excel having fixed number of rows. Do you intend to go to the bottom of the sheet repeating this pattern? You can use a For Loop.

Answer (score 1):

The closest you're going to get to infinity is 10,485 complete sets of 100 cells, since there are only 1,048,576 rows in a worksheet. Assuming you really need to go all the way down to the bottom, a simple for loop would do the trick:

```
Range("A1").Select
For i = 1 To 1048500
    If ActiveCell.Offset(i, 1) <> "" Then
        ActiveCell.Offset(i, 0).Value = Int(i / 100) + 1
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Works great! Thank you for your help! To take one step further, if I have I were to apply a label in row 1, how would A adjust the code to start the count in row two and then number 100 rows?